# How can I get a website sub-directory to use sub-domain url?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 website (mysite.com) and will be adding new functionality to the project at mysite.com/talk.  The kicker is I need the /talk sub-directory to be accessed and utilized using talk.mysite.com as the url.  How can I do this in .net or IIS 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options here.

1. Add a [URL rewrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) rule -- match the incoming hostname `talk.mysite.com` and rewrite it to `mysite.com/talk`.
2. Create a new website within IIS (pointing to the /talk directory) and modify its binding information.  Set the "hostname" so that it will only accept traffic on `talk.mysite.com`.
3. Perform a redirect at the ASP.Net application level.  Add an `Application_BeginRequest` handler to  global.asax, and redirect if Request.Url.Host is `talk.mysite.com`.

The best one depends on the details of your scenario.  I think #1 is probably the easiest (most straightforward), but one of the others might be a better fit in some cases.